# Is it possible to do Reverse Engineering in Blackberry to get code for .cod file.?

Tags: blackberry, reverse-engineering

I have some .cod files and want to use some features from those files , so that i want to do reverse engg in blackberry.Is it possible.If yes,then how?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you mean you want to decompile it, not reverse engineer it? There are some decompilers out there that exist for BlackBerry COD files, but I've read on the BB forums that people say they don't work too well. However, from your post it sounds like you are trying to use someone else's COD file, which would be illegal. If they wanted you to have the source, they'd make it available.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's possible to extract .class files and view them with jshrink?